# Custom ostream without flushing?

Tags: c++, ostream, sstream

Currently I create an ostream with a custom stringbuf derived object, but it uses sync() to print text on the screen. Is there a way to avoid having to flush it? I really want to do logStream << "Test"; without std::flush or endl.

Comment: I'm sure you can tag it a little better. C++ ?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to think of tags to tag it with and got stumped. Fixed.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want it to be flushed, or that you want it to be flushed without being told?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to this related question: [Custom stream to method in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366904/custom-stream-to-method-in-c/4366995#4366995)

All you really need to change is to add the flush instead of the function call and your stream instead of the stringstream.

**Edit:** Just saw that was your question. The answer still works though.

Comment: You didn't have a code snippet of it, so I didn't quite understand what you meant.