# How to overload operator << to act like what ostream does

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am on implementing a class, and I'd like to pass some parameters to the instance using <<.

For example,

```
terminal term;
term << "Hello World!" << '\n';
```

The code goes below,

```
class terminal {
    template <typename T>
    terminal& operator << (T& t) {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Basically, I'd like to be a stream instead of being the part of stream. (not cout << term;)

(Sorry for that I forgot to specify my question)
The question is, it worked well with strings, but it compiled failed if there is a number (like int, char, etc).

If we use the example above, the compiler will complain that

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('terminal' and 'int')

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: `T& t` make that `const T&` and you should be set.

Comment: Can you post the code which generated the error, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366904/custom-stream-to-method-in-c
This link might solve your problem.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you! You just solved my problem! It needs to be const T&.

Comment: @Angew I'm so sorry that I even forgot to write what my problem is. And the problem just solved, but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change to the following, in order for sequencing of `operator<<` (e.g., `term << "hello" << std::endl;` ) to work:

```
namespace foo {

class terminal {    
  std::ostream &strm;
public:
  terminal(std::ostream &strm_) : strm(strm_) {}
  terminal() : strm(std::cout) {}

  template <typename T>
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(terminal &term, T const &t);
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(terminal &term, T const &t) {
  term.strm << t;
  return term.strm;
}

}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78d01b14307237b8)

Comment: Thank you. This implementation considers  ostream, better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `operator <<` takes its argument by reference to non-const, which means it can only bind to lvalues. So things like non-string literals are out. If you do not need to modify the argument, take it by `const &` instead. The language has a special rule which allows lvalue references to `const` to bind to rvalues as well.

```
terminal& operator << (const T& t) {
    std::cout << t;
    return *this;
}
```

If you *do* need to modify the argument, use a different approach than `<<`. A stream-like interface which would modify the streamed arguments during `<<` would be extremely counterintuitive and a maintenance nightmare.